# Why does the VirtialBox Guest Additions need Multiple Installations

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox:
Win10/64-bit VM hosted by Win7/64-bit

Sometimes I get the full screen, sometimes I don't.  Sometimes I get shared folders, sometimes I don't.  It seems that the VirtualBox Guest Addition can fix this.  So, after installing the Guest Additions, this fixed it until I rebooted!

I installed the Guest Additions when I first created the VM.  I installed it several times afterwards.  Each time it appears to be installed as if it was never installed previously, requiring a reboot!

- Why does it need to be installed several times?
- Why does it appear that every time I install it, it is the "first time" it has ever been installed
- Is there another way that my VM can "perceive" my wide screen and auto-resize to the full screen without installing the Guest Additions again?

Comment: It doesn't and shouldn't.  You could have a corrupted install of Windows 7.  Are you using snapshots?

Comment: I am now!  I have been doing so with a recent Win10VM.  I noticed this on both Linux and Windows VM's.  I notice it most often with the wide screen issue - perhaps it is not detecting my screen well?  However, I could swear I saw it with shared folders as well.